# How to capture DWM window buffers for virtual reality app

Tags: windows-10, virtual-reality, dwm

I want to be able to build something similar to the now defunct vr program Envelop. It allows you to interact with your Windows 10 windows in a VR space
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPCq089MQDI

From reading on wikipedia i see that windows write to an off screen buffer provided to them by Window's DWM

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager

It looks like this offscreen buffer is hanging out somewhere down near the GPU ram. So it seems like I should be able to get reference to that spot in memory and draw a 3d mesh with it. Is that possible? How do I find the reference?

Looking at the DWM api it looks like you can request Windows to draw a copy of another app's contents into your draw area, but they mention specifically that you can't use it to a 3d thing since its windows doing the drawing and it does it in 2d

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541(v=vs.85).aspx

How can I use windows textures in my 3d app? Also, if there is a better approach using universal apps, or virtual desktops or some such thing, I am all ears.

Comment: The person in the video seems to have figured it out, but their website is dead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRTgFTMnT_U

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense now, but there's GitHub repository for the guy on that channel.[steeve/dwmaxx2](https://github.com/steeve/dwmaxx2)

Comment: And I'm not sure if you're still interested or if these are appropriate, but this article may be relevant. [Windows.Graphics.Capture Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture?view=winrt-22000), [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture), [Screen capture to video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video)